# NetSuite Custom Field for Kit/Package Records that references member line items

Tags: netsuite

Is it possible to create a custom field on Kit/Package records that will display member line items?

For example: There is a Kit/Package that contains two components. Is it possible to have a custom field called "Component SKU 1". This field will populate with the SKU of the first line item {memberline}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a beforeSubmit User Event script that will run a search against member items and populate the custom fields with the data you want. I did a little testing and am confident this is not something that could be accomplished through a simple field level sourcing. Creating this user event should be simple enough assuming you have some SuiteScript and Javascript knowledge. As a start though you should really only need to use the 'N/record' and 'N/search' modules if using SuiteScript 2.0. Information on both can be found easily enough in Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly build a User Event script that populates a set of custom item fields.
What is your use case?

Comment: The custom fields will be used on Kit/Package records. Each Kit/Package record will have two component SKUs. There will be two custom fields on each Kit/Package record: (1) for component SKU #1 and (2) for component SKU #2. The custom fields will be used to pull each component into a Saved Search that will be used to generate an Advanced PDF/HTML template. It's a creative way to get around the roadblock of not being able to used a Summary Saved Search to generate an Advanced PDF/HTML template.